# Sitecore Glass Childlist Runtime Error

Tags: sitecore, glass-mapper

I'm working in a Sitecore project that uses Glass and code generation to create glass classes. I wanted an easy way to get a child list on every Glass class type so on IGlassBase I added

```cs
    IEnumerable<GlassBase> Children { get; set; }
```

and on GlassBase

```cs
    [SitecoreChildren]
    public virtual IEnumerable<GlassBase> Children { get; set; }
```

but I am getting a runtime error saying that Children cannot be added twice. Any ideas?

Comment: Has someone extended a model from the code generation, and included a custom property for Children on it?

Comment: Try to add the SitecoreChildren attribute on the IGlassBase interface and not on the GlassBase class.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add "SitecoreChildren" to your interface rather than your concrete class, like:

```cs
[SitecoreChildren]
IEnumerable<GlassBase> Children { get; set; }
```

This is how i have it on all of my projects, and it works fine.

hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

You Can try like this:

```
[SitecoreChildren(InferType = true)]   
IEnumerable<GlassBase> Children { get; set; }
```